# version of eclipse that comes with the adt bundle

Tags: android, eclipse, ide, adt

when you download the ADT bundle which version of eclipse comes packed? Kepler, juno? Also what are the major differences between the eclipse versions? Considering these major differences if running a different version of eclipse then the one that comes with the adt bundle would it makes sense to change versions or just add the sdk to my current version which is Kelper?

Comment: I will highly recommend to use Android Studio / Intellij to develop android apps, but if you must use eclipse you can install the adt plugin to any Eclipse version

Comment: I have it installed. I just read it was still real buggy. Do you find that its a good starting point? Plus when looking up tutorials there is not as much out there using that IDE. What are your thoughts?

Comment: I'm using Android Studio for a while now and I didn't notice many problems, sometimes it wont compile app and I have to restart it but this not happen very often so it's not a problem. But even if you don't want to use Android Studio there is Intellij on which Android Studio is based on. I find eclipse more laggy and buggy then AS/Intellij acctualy

Comment: If you have an existing Eclipse installation, then I would recommend just adding the ADT plugin to it. The ADT bundle is usually out of date, and it has no advantage over stock Eclipse.

Comment: Use the Eclipse standard edition. Then, download and install ADT separately. Note: ADT and Android SDK versions need to be the same to avoid unforseen problems. Avoid Android Studio for now as it's a work-in-progress. Use Eclipse or IntelliJ as these IDEs have been tried and tested. For Eclipse, use Juno as Keppler is still quite buggy with Android...